# QPluginLoader.instance() - how does it really work?

Tags: qt, dll, constructor

I am currently working on a Qt project where dynamic plugin loading is central. I am loading DLLs by using Qt's *QPluginLoader*. The different plugins are accessed through CameraPluginStructs, defined as follows:

```
struct CameraPluginStruct
{
    QString name;
    QString filePath;
    CameraPluginInterface* plugin;
    QPluginLoader* pluginLoader;

    CameraPluginStruct(QString filePath=nullptr, QString name=nullptr):
         filePath(filepath), name(name), plugin(nullptr), pluginLoader(nullptr){}
};
```

To load a plugin, the following function is called:

```
void loadPlugin(CameraPluginStruct& p)
{
    p.pluginLoader = new QPluginLoader(p.filePath);
    p.pluginLoader->load();

    QObject* possiblePlugin = p.pluginLoader->instance(); //QPluginLoader.instance();

   if(possiblePlugin) 
   {
       // cast from QObject to correct type:
       p.plugin = qobjectcast<CameraPluginInterface>(possiblePlugin);
   }
}
```

And to unload a plugin, I use this function:

```
void unloadPlugin(CameraPluginStruct& p)
{
    p.pluginLoader->unload();  // QPluginLoader.unload(); 
    p.pluginLoader->~QPluginLoader();

    p.pluginLoader = nullptr;
    p.plugin = nullptr;
 }
```

I have made a few, simple test plugins that write messages to the console when the constructor is called. For simplicity, let's say that I have two test plugins, DLL A and DLL B. When I load A by using the *loadPlugin()* function, the constructor in the plugin is called, and the corresponding message is written in the console. I can do the same thing with B, and everything seems to work – B's constructor message is written to the console, and the other functions seem to work as well.

Now, the problem occurs when I try to create another CameraPluginStruct connected to either A or B. No message is written to the console, which leads me to think that the constructor is not called. Even though, I am able to call the other test functions in the plugin with success (*DoSomething()*, see below). If I unload all CameraPlugins connected to A or B, and then load the DLL again, the constructor is called again on the first load.

The *QPluginLoader.instance()* call is described as follows in the documentation:

> *"Returns the root component object of the plugin. (...) The component object is a QObject. Use qobject_cast() to access interfaces you are
>   interested in."* http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html#instance

Wouldn't it then be natural that the constructor in the DLL would be called each time, and not only the first time?

As I've understood, a DLL is only loaded once for any program. Therefore I have also tried to use only one *QPluginLoader* per DLL file, with the same result. Qt also says that:

> *"Multiple instances of QPluginLoader can be used to access the same physical plugin."* http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html#details

Therefore I can't see how this can be a source to the problem anyway.

I would really appreciate if anyone could clarify how the *QPluginLoader.instance()* really works. Why is the constructor – at least how it seems – only called the first time I use the *instance()* call?

Thank you!

Here is the code found in the DLLs (the output texts differ in A and B):

```
TestDLL::TestDLL()
{
    std::cout << "This is written from the constructor in A \n";
}

QString TestDLL::Name() const
{
    return "Hello, writing from Name() \n";
}

void TestDLL::DoSomething() const
{
   qDebug() << "Hello, this text comes from DoSomething()"\n;
}
```

Comment: This is an old thread but still I noticed that you are not using `qobject_cast` completely correct. Whenever you use `qobject_cast`, `dynamic_cast` etc. you should always check for the result of that casting. If the casting has failed `qobject_cast` return 0. In your case you have `possiblePlugin` and to me it seems that if it's unequal 0 you think you definitely have a plugin of  your type, which might not always be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your plugin is loaded (i.e. the first time `QPluginLoader::instance()` is called), then a *single* instance of it is created - this is your root instance.  The root instance is the only instance `QPluginLoader` will ever create for you.

If you want more, then you create a `createInstance()` or `clone()` method for your plugin class, so that new instances can be created from the root instance.  Or more conventionally, make your plugin class a *factory* for the class type you wish to expose.